# Json compress table?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, vb.net

In my MVC project, I return like 300 rows, which has exact same structure (fields), so instead of this:

```
[{
  name : "John",
  age : 11,
}, {
  name : "Jane",
  age : 21,
}, {
  name : "Poul",
  age : 18,
}]
```

Is it possible, in vb.net (or c#), to only state the fieldnames once and return like this:

```
[["name","age"],["John",11],["Jane",21],["Poul",18]]
```

That would save me like 50% of the code returned from server to client.

Comment: but then ul have to parse it to the original way when you are iterating through it.

Comment: yes, return an `object[][]` in .Net and make your inner array contain only the values.

Comment: It is not a problem, you should ask it to send the data compressed.  You will probably save a lot more this way.

Comment: Agree with Casperah this isn't really all that much data, and you can always request the data in zipped form.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/F88qR/

Comment: @MESSIAH that does it client-side he said `is it possible in vb.net (or c#) to only state the fieldnames once and return like this:` does work though :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compression algorithm for JSON encoded packets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395505/compression-algorithm-for-json-encoded-packets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, return an `object[][]` in .Net and make your inner array contain only the values.

Example:

```
public object[][] GetUsers()
{
    List<object[]> users = new List<object[]>();
    //Get users and store them in variable called RealUsers or cycle through DataRows
    foreach(User user in RealUsers)
    {
        users.add(new object[]() {user.Name, user.Age});
    }

    return users.ToArray();
}
```